# wrong result with google sheet get sheet from another URL with condition

Tags: google-sheets

what wrong with this command

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/XXXurlXXX/edit#gid=0","sheet1!A:Z"),"select Col2 WHERE Col6 contains 'main' ")
```

the results start from second row or first or third , there is no rule for this
i need to start from first to end

i try with wrong condition like contains 'main 111' , then i get first three results in one row

[main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE9r6.png)

[result sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPBGp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/XXXurlXXX/edit#gid=0","sheet1!A:Z"),"select Col2 WHERE Col6 contains 'main'", 1)
```

Note the (optional) headers argument at the end of the query.
See if that works?